# How do I make a folder "public" accessible on a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions

In my `.htaccess` file, I updated WordPress with a "public" folder at the root.

So when for example I try to access a file present in the folder, e.a. `www.example.com/public/img.png`, I get a 404 error, so I change the permissions of the folder to 777 and I Have the same problem.

Here is the linked code on `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I want all file in "public" folder to be accessible by everyone directly by URL.

Comment: Files within WordPress are directly accessible by default.  You shouldn't need any configuration.  Maybe `public` is your document root?  So the the URL might just be `https://example.com/img.png`

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the image via the WordPress Media Library. Why over complicate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server and if it's running Apache what you can do is creating an alias by modifying `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
Alias /public /var/www/html/public
<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then you have to restart the service
`sudo service apache2 restart`